# "Aggregate and compress CSS files" and "Aggregate JavaScript files" in performance settings, is not working

Tags: performance

This thread contains the most information I've been able to find about this: [#986558: "Aggregate and compress CSS files" and "Aggregate JavaScript files" in performance settings, is not working](http://drupal.org/node/986558)

I have 2 d7 sites. One is in public_html/ on my server and has no problems. The other is in a sub-directory, and breaks when turning on Aggregation/Compression of css & js files (in admin/config/development/performance ).

When I turn on js performance, my js doesn't work. When I turn on css performance, no css loads on my site in Firefox or Chrome, but does load in Safari. According the the above-mention issue, it's because of Drupal & my server sending compressed info to the browser, which can't decompress it and thus, I get no js or css.

Following a recommendation, I disabled these in my .htaccess file:

```
#Header append Content-Encoding gzip
#Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
```

What that did, however, was break some of my css, and load a "skip to content" area in the top of my website (which, if you do theming, you might be familiar with seeing that as a hidden html element that is loaded).

I'm not sure what to do to fix this. I encountered it the first time I built this site, but was using D7-rc1. I rebuilt it hoping new core/module updates would fix it, but this site is running on D7.7 now.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I have gone through this issue and found the exact reason, not a solution. When I check "Aggregate and compress CSS files." or  "Aggregate JavaScript files." or both, I get the same error.

Well if I do the same on my local machine, the site runs like a rocket. And now I realised that the action perform there was "Drupal creating few(may be 5 to 10) compressed files that includes all the css and js files for the page. And save the files in css and js directories under /files.

Comment: At this point, the browser has no permission to create and save files in the server. As a result of this, there will be no files for the calls in the source code to these latest files.

If you are working with your local copy of Drupal, you can do this and there won't be any such a permission issue. I have got my site working like a bomb in my local machine and so bad in the server. After this, I went for other performance optimization techniques. [Now it seems like the issues is solved in Drupal-7.9- very happy though]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this issue is ongoing at http://drupal.org/node/986558 . The Drupal-7.9 should have fixed it, and it did fix my css, but I am still having issues with js.

Note: if you have this problem and upgrade to Drupal-7.9 , make 100% sure you replace all of your .htacess files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following free tools from [Online-Code](http://www.online-code.net).

- [Minify JS](http://www.online-code.net/minify-js.html)
- [Minify CSS](http://www.online-code.net/minify-css.html)

I've been using them for a long time and have had no performance issues.